# Can I make two functions with the same name but different parameters in discord.py when building a discord bot?

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I'm now working on the 8balls function in my discord bot. I want it to react when people just call '!8balls' but enter no 'questions' in the channel. It is supposed to print out a line in the channel rather than do nothing.

```
@client.command('8balls')
async def _8balls_1(ctx):
    await ctx.send(':warning:Please enter a question after the command and seperate them with a space.')

@client.command('8balls')
async def _8balls(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ["It is certain.",
"It is decidedly so.",
"Without a doubt.",
"Yes - definitely.",
"You may rely on it.",
"As I see it, yes.",
"Most likely.",
"Outlook good.",
"Yes.",
"Signs point to yes.",
"Reply hazy, try again.",
"Ask again later.",
"Better not tell you now.",
"Cannot predict now.",
"Concentrate and ask again.",
"Don't count on it.",
"My reply is no.",
"My sources say no.",
"Outlook not so good.",
"Very doubtful."]
    await ctx.send(f'Question:\"{question}\"\n Response:\"{random.choice(responses)}\"')
```

I tried to achieve polymorphism by writing like that. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. How can I fix that?

Comment: Ignoring exception in command _8balls:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zyck/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/zyck/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 847, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/home/zyck/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 784, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)

Comment: File "/home/zyck/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 690, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "/home/zyck/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 535, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: question is a required argument that is missing.

Comment: These lines of error came up when I hid the _8balls(ctx) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just handle the error if the `question` argument is not passed, no need for two separate commands.

```
@client.command('8balls')
async def _8balls(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ["It is certain.",
                 "It is decidedly so.",
                 "Without a doubt.",
                 "Yes - definitely.",
                 "You may rely on it.",
                 "As I see it, yes.",
                 "Most likely.",
                 "Outlook good.",
                 "Yes.",
                 "Signs point to yes.",
                 "Reply hazy, try again.",
                 "Ask again later.",
                 "Better not tell you now.",
                 "Cannot predict now.",
                 "Concentrate and ask again.",
                 "Don't count on it.",
                 "My reply is no.",
                 "My sources say no.",
                 "Outlook not so good.",
                 "Very doubtful."]
    await ctx.send(f'**Question**: \"{question}\"\n**Response**: \"{random.choice(responses)}\"')


@_8balls.error
async def missing_question(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(':warning: Please enter a question after the command and seperate them with a space.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload functions in Python like you would do in C or other languages. You can just give default values to your function arguments and handle that in your function:

```
def my_func(param1, param2, param3=None, param4=None):
    # your logic
```

This way you can call the function `my_func` with the 2 required parameters (param1 and param2) and can add optional parameters param3 and param4. Inside the function body you can check for the presence of the optional parameters and adjust your logic accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know that overload is not allowed in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `typing` module starting in Python 3.5 you actually can do function overloading:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#function-method-overloading